# Whatsapp transfer messages domain s.whatsapp.net is not working

Tags: api, dns, chat, whatsapp

I was using mpg25 API for chatting through WhatsApp, but WhatsApp disable the domain: s.whatsapp.net, so I am seeking about another domain to connect to WhatsApp. I used android simulator (BlueStacks) then I installed WhatsApp and activate it, and I used resource monitoring (windows tool) to catch the IP that WhatsApp using for transfer messages. I coped the catches IP and set it in constants instead of s.whatsapp.net, but that not working. I s there anyone has fixed this issue? could you help me in this issue?

Comment: Hi have you got any alternative for s.whatsapp.net. I have same problem, I am using a php library to send the message on whatsapp but not working.

Comment: Same Problem here, seems that chat-api is now working anymore?